# Condition that matches all occurrences of a word in a file ad does something

Tags: bash, scripts, grep, sed, awk

I am to do something like this

```
for (( every occurrence of the word TRAP-TYPE in a file )) 
do 
desc="$(< inputfile awk '/DESCRIPTION/ {getline; gsub(/^\s*"/, ""); gsub(/"\s*$/, ""); print}')"

casenum="$(< inputfile awk '/::=/ {gsub(/^\s*::=\s*/, ""); gsub(/\s*$/, ""); print}')"

echo $desc $numvar $casenum 
done
```

It will search for every occurrence of `TRAP-TYPE`.
Any language will do!

INPUT

> sCSISmart20   TRAP-TYPE
>           ENTERPRISE  cyclone
>           DESCRIPTION
>           "Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems"
>           --#TYPE "Aspi: unable to read the database file"
>           --#SUMMARY "ASPI: unable to read the file, server hard disk may have                                                              problems"
>           --#ARGUMENTS {}
>           --#SEVERITY WARNING
>           --#TIMEINDEX 100
>           --#STATE OPERATIONAL
>           --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"
>           --#HELPTAG 124
>       ::=  124
>
> sCSISmart21    TRAP-TYPE
>           ENTERPRISE  cyclone
>           DESCRIPTION
>           "Aspi: database is corrupted"
>           --#TYPE "Aspi: database is corrupted"
>           --#SUMMARY "ASPI: database file is corrupted"
>           --#ARGUMENTS {}
>           --#SEVERITY WARNING
>           --#TIMEINDEX 100
>           --#STATE OPERATIONAL
>           --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"
>           --#HELPTAG 125
>       ::=  125
>
> sCSISmart12    TRAP-TYPE
>       ENTERPRISE  cyclone
>       VARIABLES {cycHostAdapterNumber, cycScsiTargetID, cycLun, cycVendor,        cycProduct, cycSenseInfo}
>       DESCRIPTION
>       "The HostAdapter# %d, TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure          Condition on vendor %s product %s with sense info MSB(sense code), next  8 bits (sense code Qual) next 8 bits (Add sense code Qual) LSB (0000) %d"
>       --#TYPE "Device has SMART/Predicictive failure event"
>       --#SUMMARY "The HostAdapter# %d , TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure Condition on vendor %s product %s with senseinfo %d"
>       --#ARGUMENTS {0,1,2,3,4,5}
>       --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL
>       --#TIMEINDEX 100
>       --#STATE OPERATIONAL
>       --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"
>       --#HELPTAG 116
>   ::=  116

OUTPUT

```
Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems             
124
Aspi: database is corrupted            
125
```

Sorry for the misunderstanding. I am plagued by bad internet connectivity.

Comment: So you want to store the total number of occurences of the word and execute N times a statment right?

Comment: what command do you want to execute? Im writing the program.

Comment: @SamFlynn Can we have more information on how the output and input should look like ? Is TRAP-TYPE exact string you want to search for, or it's just placeholder for some other things ? please clarify your specifications so that we can adjust answers accordingly

Comment: @Serg and kos I have made changes. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @SamFlynn one more small question - do the files that you wanna test have any special extension, like .txt ?

Comment: @Serg yes they have an extension called .mib but they can be read as a text file.

Comment: @SamFlynn I've posted an answer , all with awk. Please review. It uses `system` function that allows running shell commands on each awk's iteration through a file or piped output.

Comment: One thing, I posted an answer to this however when processing text files whitespaces matter. So if you want an accurate and working answer make sure that the sample input reflects *exactly* the file you're going to process, i.e. it has the same number of spaces / tabs at the start, in the middle and at the end of each line, otherwise answers may become useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WORK IN PROGRESS**

Extracting data itself is easy:

`awk '{ if($0~/DESCRIPTION/){getline;print $0}; if($0~/::=/) print $2}' testfile`

Running that with testfile that contains input text you've posted , gives this output:

```
$ awk '{if($0~/DESCRIPTION/){getline;print $0}; if($0~/::=/) print $2}' testfile                      
    "Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems"
124
    "Aspi: database is corrupted"
125
```

If we're gonna have multiple files there, the code can be edited like so:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME"\n========"} { if($0~/DESCRIPTION/){getline;print $0}; if($0~/::=/) print $2}' *.test                  
file1.test
========
    "Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems"
124
    "Aspi: database is corrupted"
125
file2.test
========
    "Aspi: second file"
134
    "Aspi: i love awk"
135
```

That's just for extracting data. I will keep on editing this answer to include how you can assign exctracted data to variables.

One approach is to use awk's `system` function, that will allow running shell commands with variables passed by awk. In this function, the command has to be within double quotes, and awk's internal variables outside the quotes. For example something like this :

```
awk '{ if($0~/DESCRIPTION/){getline;printf $0"|"}; if($0~/::=/) printf $2"\n"}' *.test | awk -F'|' '{ STRING=$1;NUM=$2; system("echo this is the NUMBER "NUM" and this is the TEXT  "STRING)   }'
```

Output:

```
this is the NUMBER 124 and this is the TEXT Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems
this is the NUMBER 125 and this is the TEXT Aspi: database is corrupted
this is the NUMBER 134 and this is the TEXT Aspi: second file
this is the NUMBER 135 and this is the TEXT Aspi: i love awk
```

One possible way of assigning output to variables would be with two parralel arrays.

```
$   IFS="|"; STRING_ARRAY=($(awk ' /DESCRIPTION/ {getline;printf "%s|",$0}; /::=/ { printf $2"\n" }' trapfile.txt | awk -F'|' '{printf "%s|",$1}'))

$ echo ${STRING_ARRAY[*]}
    "Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems"     "Aspi: database is corrupted"     "Aspi: second file"     "Aspi: i love awk"
```

There, I've used internal field separator IFS `|` and created strings array as processed by the two awk commands. Now that STRING_ARRAY can be used in a for loop. To output the appropriate numbers to an array:

```
$ IFS="|"; NUMS_ARRAY=($(awk ' /DESCRIPTION/ {getline;printf "%s|",$0}; /::=/ { printf $2"\n" }' trapfile.txt | awk -F'|' '{printf "%s|",$2}'))

$ echo ${NUMS_ARRAY[*]}
124 125 134 135
```

Now we have two parrallel arrays, with each index matching string and number from each occurrence in any file

Notice that the code in the first pipe is the same, so we can simplify this, by making an awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# Author: SergKolo
# Date: June 16,2015
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/636705/295286
# Awk script to extract text
# between two specific strings
# in a file


{

          if($0~/DESCRIPTION/)
          {
            getline;printf "%s|",$0
          }; 

          if($0~/::=/) { printf $2"\n" }

}
```

Save that script in a file with some name , `chmod +x scriptname.awk`. Now those long commands simplify as:

`$ IFS="|"; LINES_ARRAY=($(trap-script.awk trapfile.txt | awk -F'|' '{printf "%s|",$1}' ))`

And

`$ IFS="|"; NUMBERS_ARRAY=($(trap-script.awk trapfile.txt | awk -F'|' '{printf "%s|",$2}' ))`

**Note:** because out of our conversation in the comments it became apparent that some of your files contain lines that have `%d` and `%s` format , characters, I've included `printf "%s|",$0`  likes in the code for a reason. When printf function expands a line $0 and sees those format characters it assumes that there must be input for them, instead of treating it as one long string. `printf "%s|",$0` allows treating those %d characters as text, not as something that needs input.

Comment: The first comand you gave me works perfectly. I was planning on storing these values line by line in a 2-D array. I just need to know all of this  being printed how can I store them in a variable?

Comment: The problem is that because of  the multiple occurences of the TRAP-TYPE in every single file, you can store the one string and one number in a variable, but I dont know how to approach storing second occurence. I'd say the last command that pipes from awk to awk can be used to store everything into an arrray with the say `system` command. I just need to think how to approach this. That's definitely feasible though

Comment: Speaking of 2d arrays, bash does not support multi-dimensional arrays. They can be simulated, but that's considered not quite an optimal solution.I suggest using two , parallel arrays.

Comment: gives me the same error         |"): run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf(" "The HostAdapter# %d with HostAdapter Id %s and Manager Id %s is discovered"
 FILENAME="adaptec.mib" FNR=231 NR=231
this is the paste of the file I am running your SECOND-LAST command on http://paste.ubuntu.com/11720181/    try running your command on this is it giving the same error?

Comment: @SamFlynn the thing is once $0 , or the whole string is expanded, and if it has variables like %d, printf treats them as substitution, not as string to be printed. Change the code to `print "%s|",$0`. I hope I understood correctly which command you meant

Comment: I understand your explanation but changing doesn't solve anything, it still says awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf("%s|")
I am talking about the SECOND-LAST command with the array STRING_ARRAY

Comment: you don't need parenthesis around printf. I'll edit my answer in a second

Comment: Edited ! Please review

Comment: They still don't work NUMS_ARRAY and STRING_ARRAY still give the same error. I am going to add another example because of which the error is happening.

Comment: Added another example. Please have a look.

Comment: @SamFlynn I've added some corrections to the last two pieces of code that store output into array. I've tested them with the examples you've posted, and everything works. The issue was that we needed `printf "%s" ` on both first and second awk command (before and after pipe). Please review and test, let me know if everything works as expected.

Comment: I've also simplified the code by a lot. There were some unnecessary bits. Let me know if I can remove the WORK IN PROGRESS tag, if you find this answer as working and if this answer satisfies your requirements, please accept it. Also, let me know if I may shorten the text only up to the script and the last two lines

Answer (score 2):

Another awk solution:

```
$ gawk -F '\n *' -v RS="::=[^\n]*\n*" '{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"", RT); printf "%s\n%s\n", $4, RT}' foo
"Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems"                           
124
"Aspi: database is corrupted"                                                  
125
```

The text naturally divides into records, but the record separator is not very straightforward. It could be two consecutive newlines. I decided to use the last field in the record (`::= ...`), followed by arbitrarily many newlines, as the record separator.

Then, for splitting on fields, I used a newline followed by arbitrarily many spaces. After that, it's just a matter of printing the fourth field, and extracting the numbers from the record separator text (`RT`). Because this solution uses `RT`, it is GNU awk-only.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, the occurences of a word could be found with
awk, grep, and sed; but you would have to incase those in a bash script
with some a case statement and an iteration. It can be done. Writing a Perl, Python, Java, or C++ program seems like a better way to go about it.

I just wrote this for you. This is a c++ program.
Copy and paste the program below into gedit. Save it as findword.cpp.
NOTE: you need to build-essential to compile it.

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential -y

:~$ g++ -o findword findword.cpp
```

The program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string wordhold = "";
    int index;
    string line;
    string trptype = "TRAP-TYPE";

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("Yourfile.txt"); // change Yourfile.txt to the name of the file

    while ( getline(infile, line) ) {

        index = line.find('\n');
        string holdword = line.substr(0,index);
        wordhold = holdword;

        if ( wordhold.compare(wordhold.size(),9,trptype) == 0 ) {

            system("Execute the command you want inside the quotes");
            wordhold = "";

        }
        else {

            wordhold = "";

        }

    }
    infile.close();

    cout << "The file is closed\nDone" << endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

By the you can run multiple commands by duplicating the system function that is in the condition statement (if).

To run the program enter the directory you compiled in and execute it from command line.

```
:~$ ./findword
```

Good luck.

Comment: I'm no `C++` expert, does this cater for  multiple occurences on the same line? However something that jumps to the eye is the fact that you're assigning an empty string to `wordhold` both in the `if` and in the `else` body, and that the `else` body is empty, so perhaps you can drop the `else` body and make an unique assignment outside of the `if` body

Comment: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/snmp/ch10_01.htm

Comment: someone else edit that program my shift keys arent working.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
< inputfile awk '/DESCRIPTION/ {getline; sub(/^ *"/,""); sub(/"$/,""); print}; /::=/ {sub(/::= */,""); print}'
```

Expanded version:

```
< inputfile awk '
    /DESCRIPTION/ {
        getline;
        sub(/^ *"/,"");
        sub(/"$/,"");
        print
    };
    /::=/ {
        sub(/^::= */,"");
        print
    }
'
```

- `/DESCRIPTION/`: selects only the records containing the string `DESCRIPTION`
- `getline`: skips the first record
- `sub(/^ *"/,"")`: substitute a string composed by any number of spaces followed by a `"` character, at the start of the line, with an empty string
- `sub(/"$/,"")`: substitute a `"` character, at the end of the line, with an empty string
- `print`: prints the record
- `/::=/`: selects only the records containing the string `::=`
- `sub(/^::= */,"")`: substitute a string composed by `::=` followed by any number of spaces, at the start of the line, with an empty string
- `print`: prints the record

Answer (score 1):

My `awk` version:

`awk '/TRAP-TYPE/ {traptype=1}; traptype && /DESCRIPTION/ {getline; gsub(/^ +/, "", $0); gsub(/^\"/, "", $0); gsub(/\"\s+$/, "", $0); print}; traptype && /::=/ {print $2}' testfile`

or more specific

`awk '/sCSISmart.*TRAP-TYPE/ {traptype=1}; traptype && /DESCRIPTION/ {getline; gsub(/^ +/, "", $0); gsub(/^\"/, "", $0); gsub(/\"\s+$/, "", $0); print}; traptype && /::=/ {print $2}' testfile`

---

*Input*

`testfile`

```
sCSISmart20 TRAP-TYPE                                  
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                  
    DESCRIPTION                                          
    "Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems"                           
    --#TYPE "Aspi: unable to read the database file"                                 
    --#SUMMARY "ASPI: unable to read the file, server hard disk may have                                                              problems"                                     
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                                 
    --#SEVERITY WARNING                                         
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                                                    
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                                          
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                                                      
    --#HELPTAG 124                         
::=  124                                                                                            

sCSISmart21 TRAP-TYPE                                     
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                
    DESCRIPTION                                                      
    "Aspi: database is corrupted"                                                  
    --#TYPE "Aspi: database is corrupted"                                          
    --#SUMMARY "ASPI: database file is corrupted"                                              
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                                                             
    --#SEVERITY WARNING                   
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                           
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                              
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                        
    --#HELPTAG 125
::=  125
```

---

*Output*

```
Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems
124
Aspi: database is corrupted
125
```

---

*Separate outputs*

`awk '/TRAP-TYPE/ {traptype=1}; traptype && /DESCRIPTION/ {getline; gsub(/^ +/, "", $0); gsub(/^\"/, "", $0); gsub(/\"\s+$/, "", $0); print;}' testfile`

```
Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems
Aspi: database is corrupted
```

`awk '/sCSISmart.*TRAP-TYPE/ {traptype=1}; traptype && /::=/ {print $2}' testfile`

```
124
125
```

Comment: Okay printing part is alright, I am still to store it in a array, ie, in one array the description and in other array the number.